# Value error when converting json file into csv

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have json file something looks like as below and I want to convert this json file into csv file.
When I run the code, it gives me value error.
Can someone please let me know how to convert below json into csv?

```
[{"VESSEL_NO":"99999","SYSTEM_NAME":"ANEMOMETER","SYSTEM_INSTANCE":"1","EVENT_TIME":"2022-03-05 00:00:00.000","DATA":"{\"/TRUE_WIND_DIRECTION\" : 350.1, \"/TRUE_WIND_SPEED\":22.9}"},{"VESSEL_NO":"99999","SYSTEM_NAME":"ANEMOMETER","SYSTEM_INSTANCE":"1","EVENT_TIME":"2022-03-04 23:59:30.000","DATA":"{\"/TRUE_WIND_DIRECTION\" : 351.4, \"/TRUE_WIND_SPEED\" : 25.85}"},{"VESSEL_NO":"99999","SYSTEM_NAME":"ANEMOMETER","SYSTEM_INSTANCE":"1","EVENT_TIME":"2022-03-04 23:59:00.000","DATA":"{\"/TRUE_WIND_DIRECTION\" : 354.5, \"/TRUE_WIND_SPEED\" : 24.3}"},{"VESSEL_NO":"99999","SYSTEM_NAME":"ANEMOMETER","SYSTEM_INSTANCE":"1","EVENT_TIME":"2022-03-04 23:58:30.000","DATA":"{\"/TRUE_WIND_DIRECTION\" : 351.9, \"/TRUE_WIND_SPEED\" : 23.1}"},{"VESSEL_NO":"99999","SYSTEM_NAME":"ANEMOMETER","SYSTEM_INSTANCE":"1","EVENT_TIME":"2022-03-04 23:58:00.000","DATA":"{\"/TRUE_WIND_DIRECTION\" : 354.1, \"/TRUE_WIND_SPEED\" : 24.9}"},{"VESSEL_NO":"99999","SYSTEM_NAME":"ANEMOMETER","SYSTEM_INSTANCE":"1","EVENT_TIME":"2022-03-04 23:57:30.000","DATA":"{\"/TRUE_WIND_DIRECTION\" : 4.7, \"/TRUE_WIND_SPEED\" : 21.4}"},{"VESSEL_NO":"99999","SYSTEM_NAME":"ANEMOMETER","SYSTEM_INSTANCE":"1","EVENT_TIME":"2022-03-04 23:57:00.000","DATA":"{\"/TRUE_WIND_DIRECTION\" : 3.4, \"/TRUE_WIND_SPEED\" : 22.4}"},{"VESSEL_NO":"99999","SYSTEM_NAME":"ANEMOMETER","SYSTEM_INSTANCE":"1","EVENT_TIME":"2022-03-04 23:56:30.000","DATA":"{\"/TRUE_WIND_DIRECTION\" : 358.1, \"/TRUE_WIND_SPEED\" : 25.3}"}]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('data.json')

ValueError: Expected object or value
```

Answer (score 1):

`read_json()` is used to read JSON files:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json("data.json")
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: i've actually used pd.read_json, there were a typo

Comment: Then probably your JSON file isn't formatted properly. That snippet working on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **json_normalize()**:

```
import json
import ast

with open ('your_json_file_path') as json_file:
    json = json.load(json_file)
 
df=pd.DataFrame(data={'a':json)
df=df.join(df['a'].apply(pd.Series)).drop(['a'],axis=1).drop_duplicates()

df['DATA']=df['DATA'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df=df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('DATA')))
df

    VESSEL_NO SYSTEM_NAME SYSTEM_INSTANCE EVENT_TIME /TRUE_WIND_DIRECTION   /TRUE_WIND_SPEED
0   99999   ANEMOMETER  1   2022-03-05 00:00:00.000 350.1   22.9
1   99999   ANEMOMETER  1   2022-03-04 23:59:30.000 351.4   25.85
2   99999   ANEMOMETER  1   2022-03-04 23:59:00.000 354.5   24.3
3   99999   ANEMOMETER  1   2022-03-04 23:58:30.000 351.9   23.1
4   99999   ANEMOMETER  1   2022-03-04 23:58:00.000 354.1   24.9
5   99999   ANEMOMETER  1   2022-03-04 23:57:30.000 4.7     21.4
6   99999   ANEMOMETER  1   2022-03-04 23:57:00.000 3.4     22.4
7   99999   ANEMOMETER  1   2022-03-04 23:56:30.000 358.1   25.3
```

Answer (score 0):

For me working double [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
import json

with open ('data.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('DATA').apply(json.loads)))

print (df)
  VESSEL_NO SYSTEM_NAME SYSTEM_INSTANCE               EVENT_TIME  \
0     99999  ANEMOMETER               1  2022-03-05 00:00:00.000   
1     99999  ANEMOMETER               1  2022-03-04 23:59:30.000   
2     99999  ANEMOMETER               1  2022-03-04 23:59:00.000   
3     99999  ANEMOMETER               1  2022-03-04 23:58:30.000   
4     99999  ANEMOMETER               1  2022-03-04 23:58:00.000   
5     99999  ANEMOMETER               1  2022-03-04 23:57:30.000   
6     99999  ANEMOMETER               1  2022-03-04 23:57:00.000   
7     99999  ANEMOMETER               1  2022-03-04 23:56:30.000   

   /TRUE_WIND_DIRECTION  /TRUE_WIND_SPEED  
0                 350.1             22.90  
1                 351.4             25.85  
2                 354.5             24.30  
3                 351.9             23.10  
4                 354.1             24.90  
5                   4.7             21.40  
6                   3.4             22.40  
7                 358.1             25.30
```